# Как увеличить размер буфера LogCat в Android Studio?

Tags: android

Как увеличить размер буфера LogCat в Android Studio?

Баг это или нет. Но суть в том что если я делаю запрос на сервер и получаю ответ. Я вывожу даанные в LogCat. Но данные отображаются урезанными если текст слишком длинный. Вывожу их в log.e

Можно ли как то увеличить размер буфера LogCat, чтобы текст полностью отобразился?

Или это дело не в буфере?

Comment: У логката есть ограничение на объем хранимых данных, при превышении которого буфер очищается. Увеличить объем данных можно на устройстве/эмуляторе в настройках, во вкладке "Для разработчиков"

Comment: @0xFFh, У меня нет пунтов типо увеличить размер буффера. Можно чуть пдоробнее как найти этот пунт на gynemotion?

Comment: в настройках -> для разработчиков -> размер буфера журнала
P.S Хотя и не ручаюсь за то, что эта опция будет называться точно так же в какой-нибудь китайской прошивке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606118/3212712) длина строки в logCat имеет некоторое ограничение. Так что вам надо резать вашу длинную строку на части и выводить их частями. Например так

```
int maxLogSize = 1000;
for(int i = 0; i <= veryLongString.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
    int start = i * maxLogSize;
    int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize;
    end = end > veryLongString.length() ? veryLongString.length() : end;
    Log.v(TAG, veryLongString.substring(start, end));
}
```

---

Либо в настроках студии выставить больший предел до обрезания строки [так:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277199/3212712)

Comment: пробовал и файл менял в ручную и в настройках менял. Все равно урезанно

Comment: Разрезание строки не помогает? Режьте на части по 50 символов-так то должно быть получится

Comment: нет я пробовал только в настроках. Код который вы выслали не делал. Просто я хотел получить ответ как увеичить размер отображения в консоли.

У меня переменная содержим 50 000байт. А отображается в консоли только 3000