# Java: HttpURLConnection: обрезается ответ по GET

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь загружать XML со списком курсов валют с адреса: http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp

Код:

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... path) {

            String content;
            try {
                content = getContent(path[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                content = ex.getMessage();
            }

            return content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

            contentText = content;
            contentView.setText(content);
            webView.loadData(content, "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Данные загружены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        private String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                c.setReadTimeout(30000);

                c.connect();


                String temp = c.getContentEncoding();
                Log.d(TAG, "Encoding: " + temp);


                String contentType = c.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
                Log.d(TAG, "Content type: " + contentType);


                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(), "windows-1251"));
                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buf.append(line + "\n");
                }

//                Scanner s = new Scanner(c.getInputStream(), "windows-1251").useDelimiter("\\A");
//                String answer = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";

                String answer = buf.toString();


                Log.d(TAG, "String get: " + answer);
                Log.d(TAG, "Длина ответа: " + answer.length());
                return (answer);
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Привел код только класса, который загружает данные.

Данные загружаются не полностью, обрезаются где-то на 2/3.

В лог выводится: длина строки: 5563

Если BufferedReader заменить на Scanner, полученная строка имеет длину 5804.

Почему по GET страница считывается не полностью? Что я делаю не так?

Полностью код тут: https://github.com/miller7777777/HttpUrlConnectionTest

**Update: данные загружаются полностью, но в LogCat выводятся не полностью. Строка, выводимая в LogCat, имеет ограничение по длине.**

Comment: Используйте что-то более адекватное, вроде retrofit, ну или okhttp, или volley, зачем вам asynctask и httpurlconnection?

Comment: Сейчас проверил - длина 5804 является правильной, что не так? Если просто скопировать xml в текстовый редактор, длина будет вообще 5345. Вы пробовали парсить?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Очевидно, проблема в другом: в лог оно выводится не полностью. Сделал TextView, туда страница выводится полностью, а в лог - нет. Из-за этого мозг сломал. Retrofit и любые другие сторонние библиотеки по условиям задания использовать нельзя, парсить - либо руками, либо SimpleXML.

Answer (score 1):

Выявлено: строка, выводимая в LogCat, имеет ограниченную длину.

Подробнее: [Как увеличить размер буфера LogCat в Android Studio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609942/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-logcat-%D0%B2-android-studio)

Явилось для меня неприятным сюрпризом.

Comment: А зачем вам, извините, выводить xml в логи ?) Попробовали бы сразу парсить, и если бы нашли ошибки, то уже копали бы дальше

Comment: Ну, я не настоящий сварщик (с)

Comment: 5 минут на редактирование комментария, не успел. Смысл в том, что я делаю задачу поэтапно: загрузка - парсинг - вывод в удобном виде распарсенных данных - - действия с данными (рассчет курса обмена одной валюты к другой). Пока сделал загрузку. Визуально проконтролировать загрузку данных в TextView или WebView ума не хватило, решил вывести в лог, по наивности думал, что в лог выведется полностью. Увидел, что в логе данные обрезаны и запаниковал: данные загрузились не полностью! Отдельная песня будет с парсингом, вообще не представляю, как за него взяться, никогда не делал.

Comment: Используйте одну из технологий, что я перечислил в первом комментарии, не мучайтесь с этим, прошу вас :)  Почитайте вот это: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html гораздо проще же.

Comment: Я не могу использовать для работы с сетью ни одну из технологий, перечисленных Вами - по условиям задания. Только то, что из коробки. Для парсинга могу использовать только SimpleXML, опять же, по условиям задания. Приходится мучиться.